AMS1117 3.3V unexpected output
I have a circuit like this...


I am measuring 3.9V at the input and only 2.89V at the output of AMS1117 3.3V
I have tried to pull out the LDO from the board and just supplied Ground and the V+ input, and I do measure the same reading on the output PIN.
Can this be due to bad LDO (counterfeit) IC or am I missing something else?

This particular regulator does not need to be counterfeit to be bad - it comes like that as default. If I remember correctly it is very picky with ESR of the output caps. Maybe you placed too good and modern caps there... Just don't use this regulator.

Check whether the AMS1117's drop out fits your idea of LDO.

@greybeard Actually don't do that. The original datasheet from the original manufacturer causes my browser to see red and call it a security risk. Such a professional company! Advanced Mo***ic Systems

@greybeard I found the datasheet on digikey though https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/5011/AMS1117.pdf. And you are correct - typical 1.2V@1A dropout.

"measuring 3.9V at the input" Too low to produce 3.3 V reliably. But there could be other issues as well as stated in the other comments.

@Lundin then, why I do still measure 2.89, when I pull it out from the PCB (where the output connected is detached from the PCB)? Any idea? Note: When I pull out from PCB, I am missing the output CAP.

(No problems with http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf - other than advanced specmanship.)

@greybeard Firefox says it's an insecure download. Maybe you are using another browser which isn't as picky about your computer's well-being.

@RakeshMehta Measure where, how? With the part gone you shouldn't have any voltage, obviously.

@Lundin Take out the LDO from PCB. Connect the input pin and ground using wires to the PCB (at the same place where the part is originally placed) and measuring output voltage using a multimeter.

@RakeshMehta Ok yeah you'll get around 2.9V then as expected. I posted an answer.


I am measuring 3.9V at the input and only 2.89V at the output of AMS1117 3.3V

As mentioned in the friendly datasheet, the dropout voltage goes from 1V typical @100mA up to 1.3V maximum @1A. So what you are measuring is the expected behavior - the part doesn't get better than this. You need a higher input voltage.
Or ideally pick a better regulator, since this particular one is infamous for poor stability and requiring expensive tantalum caps on the output in order to get a certain expected ESR.

May be that is the only good option to replace that LDO with a better one.. I need to find one with same case to put on the PCB and check. I'll update this again, once I can do it.
